Как настроить выравнивание кода в webstorm?
Перехожу с vs code на webstorm и столкнулся с проблемой отступов. Когда сохраняешь текст в vs code то там так удобно выстраивается код по иерархии тегов, чего не вижу в webstorm. И помогите разобраться с автосохранением, привык тревожно клацать cmnd s, а тут с автосохранением становится еще тревожнее т.т

Может быть это Prettier занимается "выстраиванием кода"? Если так, то нужно просто включить отработку Prettier'а при сохранении

Настройка Стиля Кода:

Чтобы настроить стиль кодирования, используйте следующую комбинацию клавиш:

Для Windows/Linux: Ctrl+Alt+S
Для macOS: Cmd+,

Это откроет окно настроек IDE.

В настройках перейдите к разделу Editor | Code Style.

Выберите язык, для которого вы хотите настроить стиль кода (например, HTML, JavaScript, CSS и т.д.).

Примените желаемые изменения в настройках отступов, пробелов, переносов и т.д.

Вы можете использовать кнопку Apply для сохранения изменений и OK, чтобы закрыть окно.


Для реформатирования кода уже в редакторе:

Выделите код или откройте файл, который вы хотите отформатировать.
Используйте Ctrl+Alt+L (Windows/Linux) или Cmd+Alt+L (macOS) для реформатирования выделенного кода.

Работа с Автосохранением:
WebStorm автоматически сохраняет изменения в коде, о чём вам не нужно беспокоиться. Однако, если вы все же хотите вручную сохранять файлы (по старой привычке), методы автосохранения можете отключить или настроить:

Откройте настройки File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings.

В строке поиска введите "autosave" для более быстрого доступа к нужным параметрам.

Вы увидите опции, связанные с автосохранением. Отсюда вы можете отключить автоматическое сохранение файлов и проектов при потере фокуса окном IDE или через заданные интервалы времени.


Для более подробной информации по настройке вы можете перейти по ссылке на документацию WebStorm по настройке стиля кода (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-code-style.html).
Для форматирования кода на лету, можно также рассмотреть использование Prettier или других плагинов форматирования, которые можно настроить для автоматического форматирования при сохранении файла.
